# Divs criadas em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Eu estou criando meio que uma playlist (até o momento tudo nela funciona como esperado) e fiz um detalhe pra seleção de músicas onde eu criei pra cada música uma div com o nome da música, e ao invés de criar elemento por elemento por cada música na pasta eu fiz um laço pra criar divs separadas e adicionar em outra:

```
var musicas = ['Aqui', 'vai', 'o', 'nome', 'das', 'músicas'];
var musics = document.querySelector('.musics');
i = 0;

while(i < musicas.length) {
    var nome_musicas = document.createElement('div');
    musics.appendChild(nome_musicas);
    nome_musicas.classList.add('name');
    nome_musicas.classList.add('music_number_' + i);
    nome_musicas.innerHTML = musicas[i];
    i++;
}
```

Meu problema agora é achar uma lógica de, quando eu clicar na div com a música ela me dar o nome da música que está dentro dela para ai eu fazer outro passo pra tocar a música selecionada.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem sua dúvida basta que você crie uma função que receba o nome da música como parâmetro e nela você pode desenvolver a lógica que desejar, seria algo assim:

```
function play(music) {
    console.log(music)
}
```

Tendo criado a função basta adicionar no evento de clique do elemento que você deseja

```
nome_musicas.onclick = () => play(musicas[i])
```

seu código final seria mais ou menos assim:

```
var musicas = ['Aqui', 'vai', 'o', 'nome', 'das', 'músicas'];
var musics = document.querySelector('.music');
i = 0;

function play(music) {
    console.log(music)
}

while(i < musicas.length) {
    var nome_musicas = document.createElement('div');
    musics.appendChild(nome_musicas);
    nome_musicas.classList.add('name');
    nome_musicas.classList.add('music_number_' + i);
    nome_musicas.innerHTML = musicas[i];
    nome_musicas.onclick = () => play(musicas[i])
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Entendi! É que nas outras funções da playlist (passar a musica, voltar de musica, deixar aleatório e auto passar a música quando uma acaba) eu usava um contador que pegava a posição da musica na lista e passava pra tag audio reproduzir. Ai minha idéia nessa criação de divs pra ser a lista de músicas era de que quando eu clicasse em uma div ela me desse o nome da música dentro dela e eu checar em qual posição da 'musicas' ele ta na variavel e passar essa posição pro contador pra ele reproduzir a música escolhida.

Answer (score 1):

1. Em HTML os atributos [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) formam uma classe de atributos, chamados de atributos de dados personalizados, que permitem que informações proprietárias sejam trocadas entre o HTML e sua representação [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/DOM) por meio de script.
2. O método [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) executa um callback fornecido uma vez para cada elemento da array.
3. A propriedade [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) permite o acesso, leitura e escrita, a todos os atributos de dados personalizado `data-*` no elemento. A propriedade mapeia um [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/DOM/DOMStringMap) cada atributo de dados personalizado.

```js
const songs = ['Aqui', 'vai', 'o', 'nome', 'das', 'músicas'];
const soundtracks = document.querySelector('.soundtracks');

//Para cada elemento da array songs onde val é o elemento e idx seu índice na array
songs.forEach(function(val, idx) {
  const btn = document.createElement('button');     //Usei botões pois achei que são semanticamente mais adequados a seletores de música, mas poderia ser usado um div com ARIA: button role para tecnologia assistiva.
  btn.classList.add('name');
  btn.dataset.number = idx;                        //Salva no atributo data-number o índice da música.
  btn.innerText = val;                             //Ajusta o texto do botão para o nome da música.
  //Adiciona o evento click ao botão
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(`Tocando agora: ${songs[e.target.dataset.number]}`);
  });
  soundtracks.append(btn);
});
```

```css
.soundtracks {
  display: grid;
}

.soundtracks button {
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.soundtracks button:hover {
  background: navy;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="soundtracks">
</div>
```